# Java: Get windows color

Tags: java, windows, colors, window, system

I'll be brief: How do I get the color that the user can specify on the windows platform? On windows 10 it's the color of the tiles when you open the start menu. `SystemColor` doesn't work, it just returns the color `153 180 209` (a light blue) for `SystemColor.activeCaption` no matter what the setting is set to on every version of windows. `UIManager` is practically useless. The names of the keys seem to be different on every version of windows. It seems that `SystemColor` works on Mac and Linux. Any ideas as to how I get this color? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do this recently. There is a value in the windows registry called `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\AccentColor`, that stores the system window title color. You can use JNA's `Advapi32Util` to read the value from the Windows registry.

You can then use a graphics library like `java.awt.Color` to convert the color into RGB values.

There is an implementation of this [here](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chrisrm/idea/utils/WinRegistry.java)